# Managing include statement

Tags: php

I have 4 files:

- index.php
- a.php
- b.php
- config.php

File **a** and **b** need to include **config.php** and index.php needs to include **a.php** & **b.php**

So the index.php will look something like:

```
<?php include('a.php'); include('b.php'); ?>
```

My question is, how would you manage the include of the file **config.php**. Should I include it in **a.php** and **b.php** or just once in **index.php** or do you have another idea.

Comment: "or do you have another idea" - you could structure your code into classes and use [autoloading](http://php.net/autoload) instead of manually specifying the includes. (You still need one include at the top of index.php, to load config.php and set up the autoloader.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do all your files (except index.php) need the configuration? If so, I would advise to always include *config.php* in *index.php*:

```
// index.php
require_once ('config.php');
```

You could of course use also include *config.php* in *a.php* or *b.php*, but I would not recommend that practice since this leads to lots of unnecessary includes (bad code).

Comment: I tried to include config.php in index.php but looks like that the code in A and B can't access to config.php functions .. "Fatal error: Call to undefined function check()"

Comment: @ImriPersiado The *order* of includes is important.

Comment: @ImriPersiado It should actually work. Please post the file contents in the question. (I assume that you include A and B *after* *config.php* was included.)

Answer (score 3):

If **a** and **b** don't need to be accessed directly, there's no need to include **config.php** in them. They will pick up the variables that have already been included in **index.php**. But if they are separate pages that can be accessed directly *and/or* can be included in **index.php**, then you would want to have your include statement at the top of those pages as well.

Your best bet is to use [include_once()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) or [require_once()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)

Comment: Incidentally, `include_once` etc aren't functions, so don't need brackets. I've actually had bugs caused by that mistake (`include_once($foo) && $bar` actually means `include_once ($foo && $bar)` because the brackets don't actually enclose anything).